# Android - creating an app that uses GPS

Tags: android, gps

Android - I want to create a new app. The purpose would be for the app to randomly choose restaurants that around me via GPS. If the user does not want to eat at that restaurant, then the user would tell the app they are not interested and the app would randomly choose another restaurant. My question is: is this possible to create for the app to randomly choose restaurants around the person via GPS?

Comment: Yes its possible. You should use google places api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, you should use Google Places API or some similar services. Try to get started with [Google places doc.](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)

In my case, request looks like

```
private static final String PLACES_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={0},{1}&radius=5000&types=cafe%7Cbar&sensor=true&language={2}&key=<YOUR_PLACES_API_KEY>";
```

As you can see, I try to search cafes and bars within radius 5 km from me.

Comment: I want to notice google places api limit your requests per day. But you have a chance to increase this limit.